# What does そういうところがです mean in this exchange?

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

> なつみ 「あの…流星。」
>
> 流星　「ん？」
>
> なつみ 「ええと…痛いところとかない？」
>
> 流星  　「問題ない。もう大丈夫だ。」
>
> なつみ 「そ、そうなんだ」
>
> なつみ 「それであの…さ。改めてごめんなさい…私のせいで無理させちゃって」
>
> 流星が訝しげな目をして、なつみを見る。
>
> なつみ 「な、なによ？」
>
> 流星   「お前は…本物のなつみか？」
>
> なつみ 「ばっ――」
>
> なつみは真っ赤になって怒ろうとした。が、ふいに弱々しい顔になり
>
> なつみ 「……そうね。こんなの私らしくないか…」
>
> 流星   「……難しいな。女の子というものは…」
>
> Girl 2 「流星さん。あなたからそんな言葉が出てくるとは思いませんでした。」
>
> 流星    「なぜだ？」
>
> Girl 2  「もう…**そういうところがです**。」
>
> Girl 2  はぁ。私もそうだけど、なつみさんも大変ね…

The question is about what the **そういうところがです** at the end of this exchange means.

Context: 流星 saved Girl 1 a while back and got injured in the process, she goes to meet him wanting to say sorry to him again. He gets surprised by her sudden apology as it isn't normally like her to be this upfront. She runs away and then he says 「難しいな。女の子というものは」 and another girl who was listening in then responds with「あなたからそんな言葉が出てくるとは思いませんでした。」, and I believe そんな言葉 is referring him saying girls are 難しい. He asks her why she thought that he wouldn't say something like that and she responds with 「もう…そういうところがです。」. My question is about what she means by this. It's clearly related to do with how he responds with 「なぜだ？」 to her statement as she's referring to "that part of him" as the reason for not expecting him to say what he said. Having said that, I'm not quite sure what "part" of him she is referring to and so I will include a few of his qualities in a list. He's generally very blunt, to the point, and troublesome to deal with(for a variety of reasons). In response to the answerer (Knowing his character, 女の子を気づかう発言をするとは思わなかった is not what I would logically think as that's the complete opposite of his character(although he is very careless and can end up saying/doing things that injure others even though he didn't intend to), as very shortly after he asks one of the other girls how he can cheer her up.

Edit: added other parts of narration and a bit more explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

普段、気が荒い流星が、「難しいな」という(気弱な、あるいは、女の子を気づかう)発言をするとは思わなかった　という意味だと思います。

「そういうところ」 は、「なぜだ？」という発言から感じられる、気が荒い、あるいは、女の子の気持ちなど気にしない性格　をさしていると思います。

---

Girl2's 「そういうところが」
means she feels blunt part of Ryusei from 「なぜだ？」
and she cannot image Ryusei says 「難しいな・・」(= そんな言葉)

Answer (score 0):

The most reasonable speculation I can think of is: *that (at least Girl 2 thinks) he attracts girls even he doesn't realize it himself*.

My rationales are: 1) Girl 2 said she didn't expect that he has difficulty understanding girls; and 2) he had no idea why she said that. But it's obvious that this dialog is too loose to support my logic alone, and unknown parts of the storyline may affect correctness of my answer. If you need more knowledgeable answers, I recommend [Anime & Manga SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) or other specialized community forums.